# scrape Highcharts series.data categories?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, highcharts

I want to export chart data from [a website](https://www.cegh.at/en/exchange-market/market-data/).

Using `console.log(Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data)` I can see the data I need.

I want the values stored under `Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data[n].category` for `n` in `[0, 1, ..., N_data_points-1]` (These values are the time-stamps of the data points in the plot.)

When I try to use `JSON.stringify(Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data)` to write the whole data attribute I get `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.

How can I get that `data[n].category` values for all `n` data points?

Note that the x axis data can be obtained straightforwardly via `Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].processedXData`, but these are not the dates, just consecutive integers.

Also, I don't necessarily need to do this via console. If it's possible to get the data via, say, a Python script, that would do as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt the python/selenium script [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/trickycases-6-scrape-highcharts-plots-a6b3fc233fe6).

Most of the stuff remains as is, except for obvious changes (change the url, etc).

You can get the category data of each data point with:

```
dates = []

for i in range(len(values)):
    date = driver.execute_script('return Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data[{}].category'.format(i))

    dates.append(date[0])
```

EDIT: as pointed out in a comment, you can get the category data without a for loop using:

```
categories = driver.execute_script('return Highcharts.charts[0].userOptions.xAxis[0].categories')
```

Comment: Hi @the.real.gruycho, You can also get raw data through: `Highcharts.charts[0].userOptions.series[0].data` and categories through `Highcharts.charts[0].userOptions.xAxis[0].categories`.